# How do I automatically apply the same theme to Chromium for all new users?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, themes, chromium

Note: when I say Chromium, I mean both Google Chrome and Chromium.

What I do know about applying the same settings for applications to all new users is either defining an schema/override file in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` or copying the folder/file to `/etc/skel`.

When a new user is created, that user is automatically given the gsettings/config file.

So my question is - how do I apply a theme to Chromium and get this to apply to all users?  Does Chromium use `gsettings` type settings? If so, which ones?

Does Chromium use config files (e.g. in `~/.config`)? If so, which ones?

I happen to be using either Gnome or Unity - but I suspect any answer will apply to any desktop environment.

---

I've found this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/eOybCPPXF2g) for a similar Q for Chrome - but for Windows.

Does this apply somehow to Ubuntu ... and also to Chromium?

---

Having had a quick chat in the general room ... `/etc/chromium-browser/customizations` was mentioned - so this may give a clue on what may need to be done for themes.

Comment: it should be  in  `~.config/google-chrome/Default/` and `~.config/chromium/Default/` since it is a user config (/etc/ is global).

Answer (score 5):

## User config directory

Chromium does use a `~/.config` directory (`~/.config/chromium` - `~/.config/google-chrome` for Google Chrome), customisable using a command line flag:

```
~ man google-chrome | perl -00 -ne 'print if /\.config/'
       --user-data-dir=DIR
              Specifies  the directory that user data (your "profile") is kept
              in.  Defaults to ~/.config/google-chrome .   Separate  instances
              of  Google  Chrome  must  use  separate  user  data directories;
              repeated invocations of google-chrome  will  reuse  an  existing
              process for a given user data directory.
```

So, the simplest way to create a new configuration is to run either of these with `--user-dir=newconfig`, customize as needed, then copy over the `newconfig` directory to `/etc/skel/.config/chromium` and `/etc/skel/.config/google-chrome`.

---

## Administrative policies

The last, but perhaps the most flexible, way would be to use `/etc/chromium-browser/policies` (or `/etc/opt/chrome/policies` for Google Chrome). The Chromium [Documentation for Administrators](https://www.chromium.org/administrators) has pages for Windows, Mac and [Linux](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start).

Essentially, on Linux, you make use of JSON files in `policies/managed` and `policies/recommended`. The `managed` directory is for settings that are enforced - the user can't change them.

I'll just adapt the example given for Linux:

```
$ cat /etc/chromium/policies/managed/test_policy.json
{
  "HomepageLocation": "www.chromium.org",
  "HomepageIsNewTabPage": false
}
```

Now, on Chromium, the homepage is locked to `www.chromium.org`. Correspondingly, if the file had been in `recommended`, the user can change their home page.

The current list of policies is available [here](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3). It lists policies, their descriptions and example values.

To install a theme or an extension, the [`ExtensionInstallForcelist`](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist) policy can be used. It can't be `recommended`, only `managed`:

```
$ cat /etc/chromium/policies/managed/test_policy.json
{
    "ExtensionInstallForcelist": [
        "gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
        "jeonacmfdmkgfmmdejlinolgjomhcbmh;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    ],
}
```

This will install [the Adblock Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) and the [GData Centers 1 Council Bluffs, Iowa](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gdata-centers-1-council-b/jeonacmfdmkgfmmdejlinolgjomhcbmh) theme.

---

## `/etc/chromium-browser/customizations`

`/etc/chromium-browser/customizations/00-example` seems to indicate it can only be used for detecting plugins and adding command line flags:

```
$ cat etc/chromium-browser/customizations/00-example
##   Register plugins this way.  The two parameters are yours to fill.

#discover_registration /path/to/plugin/plugin.info library-name

##   A way to influence the running. This is read-write for you. Please
##   Append only.

#CHROMIUM_FLAGS="${CHROMIUM_FLAGS} --option=value"

##   Read-only variables guaranteed to be set, with example values.

#APPNAME='chromium-browser'
#BUILD_DIST='Ubuntu 14.04'
#DESKTOP_SESSION='ubuntu'
#LIBDIR='/usr/lib/chromium-browser'
#UPSTREAM_VERSION='34.0.1847.131'
```

(That's from `48.0.2564.116-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1111`, by the way, despite what the `UPSTREAM_VERSION` might indicate. And for some reason, only the [32-bit package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/i386/chromium-browser/filelist) on Ubuntu 14.04 has it, not the 64-bit one.)

The list of command line flags for Chromium can be found at http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/, according to
[the Chromium website](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags).

`discover_registration` doesn't seem to be [an executable command](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=discover_registration&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) - it might be a shell function, but I'm inclined to suspect these files are not parsed by our normal shells. In any case, I think this method is not sufficiently versatile, *and* it's difficult to override if all you want is for users to start off with some settings while letting them change those later. And the flags don't seem to provide a way of installing a theme or an extension.

---

## GSettings

A quick scan of `dconf-editor` on my system indicates Google Chrome doesn't use it. Neither, [apparently (thanks @Serg)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28139223#28139223), does Chromium.

---

## Conclusion

All told, either of the first two methods can be used, and Google Chrome supports whatever Chromium does, but with different paths. Where Chromium has `/etc/chromium-browser` and `~/.config/chromium`, Google Chrome has `/etc/opt/chrome` and `~/.config/google-chrome`, respectively. The first method is OK for one-time initialization, anything more would require the second method.

Since not all settings can be configured using policies, you might have to use both of them.